# d3.js: reusable clipPath for multiple svg:text elements

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have a d3.js chart with many text strings which will need to be truncated if too long.

From my research, it seems the ways to deal with text truncation in svg is to:

1. Use SVG clipPath
2. Use SVG getBBox() and loop through truncating characters until bounding box is less than max
3. Just use best guess for max character length and truncate the string
4. Perhaps insert HTML objects into the charts using foreignObject, then use css

I'm looking at Option #1, and struggling...

**Is there a way to create a clipPath of specific dimensions, then reference that clipPath for multiple svg:g or svg:text elements and have the clipPath placed within the object's local translated coordinates?**

**Is there a way to use "symbol" or "use" to make this reusable, or do I have to generate a unique clipPath for each text string?!**

Not sure if that makes sense.

Here is my crude proof of concept that doesn't work:

http://jsfiddle.net/rolfsf/9TVq2/

```
var svg = d3.select("#test")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 300)
            .attr("height", 300)
            .attr("class", "test-container");

var defs = d3.select('.test-container').append("svg:defs");

    defs.append("svg:clipPath")
        .attr("id", "textclip")
        .append("svg:rect")
        .attr("width", 200)
        .attr("height", 20)
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("clipPathUnits","objectBoundingBox");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "textgroup")
        .attr("transform", "translate(10, 100)")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#textclip)")
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "textgroup")
        .attr("transform", "translate(10, 150)")
        //.attr("clip-path", "url(#textclip)")
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question

The problem involves mismatched coordinate space between the clippath and g. The clippath needs to have the opposite coordinate space applied

see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rolfsf/6nDW6/

```
    defs.append("svg:clipPath")
    .attr("id", "textclip")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-10, -20)")
    .append("svg:rect")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("clipPathUnits","objectBoundingBox");
```